# Why won't matplotlib draw work in pycharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I want to refresh a plot each time a long loop cycles. From my googling the best option seems to be using `plt.draw()` in the loop, rather than the animation module of matplotlib, because I only want it to update when new data becomes available.

However `plt.draw()` won't work in pycharm, even though it does work in the **same interpreter** when I run via an external shell. I don't even get an empty matplotlib window. I've tried with and without interactive mode.

Matplotlib version 3.1.0

Python version 3.6.5

Pycharm 2018.1.1

Below is some code from another post that works as expected outside of pycharm, but in pycharm I just get exit code 0, not even an error.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib
#
# print(matplotlib.get_backend())


for i in range(50):
    y = np.random.random([10,1])
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    plt.clf()
```

Expect a sequence of random graphs, get nothing but exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `plt.draw()`. Try this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    y = np.random.random([10, 1])
    plt.plot(y, 'o')
    plt.pause(3)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But same result unfortunately. Only works outside of pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show()` with blocking set to false.

```
for i in range(50):
    y = np.random.random([10,1])
    plt.plot(y)
    if i <1:
        plt.show(block=False)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    plt.clf()
```